# Exporting Firestore data from Client app in Excel

Tags: excel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an online doctor appointment mobile app. I want to add an interface in the app where the doctor can extract past booking data. Is there any function by which doctors can export all the past booking data into excel.

Simply I want this:-->

Select a range of dates. 
Extract all the documents related to that date.
Export these document's data into rows of excel sheet. 
Required fields as the columns of that excel sheet.

Is there any service/way/trick that I can use to do the same

Comment: This question is pretty vague - are you asking how to write the Firestore code to select data in a range of dates and then to write that data to .xls format? Sure, that can be done but understanding the Firestore API would be a good place to start as it demonstrates how to query that data. What language and platform are you using?

Answer (score 7):

1. npm i --save exceljs
2. npm i --save firebase-admin
3. create index.js file
4. 

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Excel = require('exceljs')

var serviceAccount = require("service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mind-next.firebaseio.com"
});
const db = admin.firestore();
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook()
let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('your export sheet name')
worksheet.columns = [
    
    {header: 'username', key: 'username'},

    {header: 'creationTime', key: 'creationTime'},
    {header: 'email', key: 'email'},
    {header: 'lastSignInTime', key: 'lastSignInTime'},
    {header: 'photoURL', key: 'photoURL'},
    {header: 'providerId', key: 'providerId'}

  ]
  worksheet.getRow(1).font = {bold: true}

async function getData() {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('your export firestore collection').get();
    snapshot.forEach((doc,index) => {
            const rowIndex = index + 2
            let e = doc.data()
            worksheet.addRow({
              ...e,
            })

    });
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('yourexportfilename.xlsx')

}

getData()
```

4. Then run node index.js

Answer (score 2):

If you have a server then you can simply fetch the data and use any module to write that data to an excel file. If your app is serverless then create a cloud function which will do the same for you.
There are always modules that can do the same for you.

Both the following samples are for NodeJs.

for nodeJs=>>[Xlsx Node Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Or you can simply use "fs" to write JSON to excel. [Example](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/46033/how-to-create-an-excel-file-with-nodejs)

Comment: I am using Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Cloud firestore is the database. What language are you using for your app? Does the app has a server or is it serverless?

Comment: Firestore is the server and does not offer a direct export to excel function

Comment: @Jay In their docs [https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/] it says "Cloud Firestore is a NoSQL document database". My answer was based on that.

Are you suggesting that it is a Database server or something that can be used to implement business logic? 
If the latter is the case then can you please share some reference for the same?

Comment: My comment was in reference to a Firestore *app is serverless* which cannot exist. Firestore is an online real time database. While it has support for offline persistence, it's limited and designed to handle temporary disconnects. So yes, Firestore is a database *server* and Firebase products can be used to implement some business logic, which in cases is the portion of a system which determines how data is transformed or calculated. Take a look at [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) which offers *scalable computing power to run code in response to events*

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484869/best-way-to-use-business-logic-across-multiple-platforms-cloud-functions). Also take a look at [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) which are used to refine and control the business logic. Additionally Firebase has [database profiling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile#speed) where it will actually measure the time it takes the Firebase server to execute business logic routines.